# how to scrape all pages (1,2,3,.....n) from a website using r vest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

# I would like to read the list of .html files to extract data. Appreciate your help.

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
library(RCurl)

u0 <- "https://www.r-users.com/jobs/"
u1 <- read_html("https://www.r-users.com/jobs/")
download_folder <- ("C:/R/BNB/")
pages <- html_text(html_node(u1, ".results_count"))
Total_Pages <- substr(pages, 4, 7)
TP <- as.numeric(Total_Pages)
# reading first two pages, writing them as separate .html files
for (i in 1:TP) {
  url <- paste(u0, "page=/", i, sep = "")
  download.file(url, paste(download_folder, i, ".html", sep = ""))
  #create html object
  html <- html(paste(download_folder, i, ".html", sep = ""))
}
```

Comment: I think replacing `u1` with `u0` would be a good starting point. Could you be more informative? What is your problem? Your title is too generic. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you can find how to make better questions.

Comment: Thanks 000andy8484, have edited the code to reflect the right assignments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a potential solution:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

u0 <- "https://www.r-users.com/jobs/"
u1 <- read_html("https://www.r-users.com/jobs/")
download_folder <- getwd()  #note change in output directory

TP<-max(as.integer(html_text(html_nodes(u1,"a.page-numbers"))), na.rm=TRUE)

# reading first two pages, writing them as separate .html files 
for (i in 1:TP ) {
  url <- paste(u0,"page/",i, "/", sep="")
  print(url)
  download.file(url,paste(download_folder,i,".html",sep=""))
  #create html object
  html <- read_html(paste(download_folder,i,".html",sep=""))
}
```

I could not find the class `.result-count` in the html, so instead I looked for the page-numbers class and pick the highest returned value.
Also, the function `html` is deprecated thus I replaced it with `read_html`.
Good luck

Comment: Thanks r2evans. Will test and use it. Hope "html <- read_html(paste(download_folder,i,".html",sep=""))", gives me a consolidated file.

Comment: 'html' in the last line still returns only page 1 content.

Comment: Thanks Dave2e, really appreciate it. However, the 'html' still returns only page 1 content. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes of course the html variable is rewritten each time through the loop.  Depending on your additional data process needs you could paste all of the web pages together, store them in an array or use a (s/l/m)apply function to operate on all of the files at a later point.